# Is there a way I can plot a figure at initial and final conditions?

Tags: python, plot

The code I am using works and is written correctly, only I want to have plots of the initial and final conditions (time = 0, time = .01)

Whenever run the code to show plot at n=0,10 I get the error "show() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n'."

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10 #number of timesteps
dt = .001 #(timestep)
L = 1.0 #domain (total length)
dx = 0.1 #spacial resolution
T0 = float(q + 1) 
T1s = float(q + 1 - r)
T2s = float(q + 1 + s)
t_final = n*dt
alpha = float(p + 1)

x = np.linspace(0, L, n)

T = np.ones(n)*T0
dTdt = np.empty(n)

t = np.arange(0,t_final, dt)

for j in range(1,len(t)):
    plt.clf()
    for i in range(1,n-1):
        dTdt[i] = alpha*(-(T[i]-T[i-1])/dx**2+(T[i+1]-T[i])/dx**2)
    dTdt[0] = alpha*(-(T[0]-T1s)/dx**2+(T[1]-T[0])/dx**2)
    dTdt[n-1] = alpha*(-(T[n-1]-T[n-2])/dx**2+(T2s-T[n-1])/dx**2)
    T = T + dTdt*dt
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(x,T)
    plt.axis([0, L, 0, 14])
    plt.xlabel('Distance')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature')
    plt.show(n=0)
    plt.show(n=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, because matplotlib doesn't know what "n" is.  I suspect what you want is to replace the last seven lines with:

```
    if j == 0 or j == n-1:
        plt.figure(1)
        plt.plot(x,T)
        plt.axis([0, L, 0, 14])
        plt.xlabel('Distance')
        plt.ylabel('Temperature')
        plt.show()
```